# Flutter: How to not change textfield postion when increasing height of container in row

Tags: flutter, containers, row, textfield

I am trying to create this, but when i increase the height of container by textfield changes it position to top.

[image]

here is my code:

```
 Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: CustomTextfield(
              isPrefixIcon: false,
              bgColor: AppColors.whiteColor,
              borderColor: AppColors.blueColor,
              hintColor: AppColors.blackColor,
              isBorder: true,
              hintText: AppStrings.typeMessage,
              suffixIcon: Image.asset(AssetPaths.sendIcon,scale: 1.5,),
            ),
          ),
          sizedboxWidth5(),
          Container(
            height: 120.h,width: 40.w,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: AppColors.blueColor,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),)
          
        ]
      ),
    );
```

here is my code output

[image]

Comment: To fix this issue, you can use the Align widget to control the vertical alignment of the CustomTextfield within the Row. You can set the alignment property of Align to Alignment.center to vertically center the CustomTextfield within the Row.

Comment: @DarshanKachhadiya you mean i have to wrap CustomTextfield to Align?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Row` widget theres a properties `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment`

`mainAxisAlignment` in Row widget means the horizontally

`crossAxisAlignment` in Row widget means the vertically.

On your issue, try to change the `crossAxisAlignment` value. Check the code below:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, /// add this
  children: [
   /// ....
  ],
),
```